# Which is more pythonic/efficient, any on a listcomp or genexp?

Tags: python

I'm trying to gauge which is more pythonic.

```
if any( ( ( i % 2 == 0 and i > 4 ) for i in range(10) ) ) :
   return

if any( [ ( i % 2 == 0 and i > 4 ) for i in range(10) ] ) :
   return
```

Would the generator expression form short circuit any faster than the list comp?

Comment: It would be more efficent to use `if True` or immediately `return` in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I chose a trivial example just to demonstrate concretely with; my use case is not taken from such an expression.

Comment: Note, it would be Pythonic to follow PEP8, which means, [no spaces immediately inside parentheses, brackets, or braces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). Also, generator expressions, if they are the only argument, don't require parentheses! This is much nicer, no? `any((i % 2 == 0 and i > 4) for i in range(10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a genexp.

The list comp will fully evaluate before running through `any`, while the genexp will not. `any` will short-circuit on the first `True` value, so you save yourself evaluations this way.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if `any` would wind up concocting a list  anyways. I'm starting to appreciate more these genexp's and am slowly starting to push the code base I work on to use those in lieu of list comps and for loops when appropriate.

Comment: @jxramos *generally* the genexp will be faster. The most common counterexample is `str.join` (because it ends up constructing a list anyway)

Comment: @AdamSmith in my experience, *generally* list comps are faster unless there is short-circuiting behavior, or the final list would be large, something like >1,000,000. Try it with different size of n for `sum(i for i in range(n))` vs `sum([i for i in range(n)])`. The true advantage of genexp's is memory efficiency. On my machine, genexp version was not faster until around n == 5000000